# SSRS 2005 line graph Series / Interval

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Afternoon all,

I have a simple bar graph in SSRS 2005 that displays data in a web page.  The space that i have allocated on the web page is very small but is required.

I have a report that pulls data back for the last 24hrs and plots this on a graph.  I have placed 'Timestamp' data on to my graph and it is located at  within the 'Drop category fields here' section.

As the space that i have for my chart is only small the 24hr timestamp labels look too busy and look messy.  Is there a way i can format this area so it only displays a label on the 6th, 12th, 18th and 24th interval?

I have reduced the label already by formatting the timestamp using the below but think i need to reduce the number of labels for the timestamp.

```
=Format(Fields!TimeStamp.Value, "H:mm dd-MMM")
```

Regards
Bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the **Major gridlines** interval:

[image]

Which gives me a result with some junk data:

[image]

So it might not be 100% perfect for what you want, but hopefully will be helpful. Unfortunately SSRS 2005 charts are a bit limited in functionality so it's a case of trying to do the best with what you have.